# Map scale in GISTools package R

Tags: r, maps, scale, gis, rworldmap

I am trying to get a simple map for the Alpine region in R, using the libraries rworldmap and rworldxtra. I will then add points in the map for locating specific sites.

For adding a north arrow and a map scale that look nicer I was trying the functions north.arrow() and map.scale() from the package 'GISTools'.
I suppose this package was developed for US, and for drawing the scale it requires a transformation function from/to feet, and I cannot figure out how to make it working with the correct proportions...

Here is the code:

```
library(rworldmap); library(rworldxtra); library(GISTools)
newmap <- getMap(resolution="high", projection=NA)
plot(newmap, xlim=c(5.7,16.6), ylim=c(46,46), asp=1.5, col="gray90")
north.arrow(xb=11.7, yb=45.4, len=0.1, lab="N",cex.lab=0.8,col='gray10')

map.scale(10, 45,ft2km(10000),"Km", 4, 0.5) #here is the headache...
```

[image: It looks nice, but the proportions are not correct...]

Answer (score 2):

You're telling `map.scale` that the length of the bar is 3.048 kilometers (i.e. `ft2km(10000)` but you're also specifying 4 divisions of the bar in 0.5 increments, thus the length does not match the number of divisions and sub-divisions you've specified.

Also, it is not necessary to use `ft2km` and I'm not sure what effect that has. You specify the units as `"Km"` in the `map.scale` function, therefore the length should be given as the number of kilometers, according to the documentation.

This looks pretty good to me:

`north.arrow(xb=7, yb=43, len=0.1, lab="N",cex.lab=0.8,col='gray10')`

`map.scale(7, 42.5,2,"Km", 2, 1)`

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It looks nice, but the scale is not correct (see the uploaded picture). I think it could be due to the "map units" of the downloaded map. I checked the help guide of the function, but I really do not get what do they mean with map units...